# How to remember 10 last read articles with timestamp in session for a user in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I would like to make a **PHP if condition code** that will check if the last 10 articles or 10 minutes from the article reading by the user have already elapsed.

E.g.

A user open a page with **id = 235** (this id value is in the url localhost/article/235 )

and this **id** value will be saved in session with a **current timestamp** and maybe **his IP address**

Then he read another article and the same will happen.

**I need to remember the clicked stuff for another ten clicks and then reset that only for the first row. E.g. after the 10th click the id and timestamp will not became 11th row but will replace the 1st row in the list.**

The php condition in CodeIgniter will then check these values and will update the article hit counter value in the articles table and column counter like this:

```
   $this->db->where('id', $id);
   $this->db->set('counter', 'counter+1', FALSE);
   $this->db->update('articles');
```

But before calling this code I need to make this check from the session?

How to do that?

I think storing e.g. 10 entries in the session with timestamps per user will be enough.

Just don't save the same page in the session twice.

And the condition will check the current timestamp with the saved one and if it is more than e.g. 10 minutes or the user have read/clicked another 10 articles it will allow the update counter php code.

I don't need to have this bulletproof. Just to disable the increment using browser's refresh button.

**So, if he wants to increment the counter he will need to wait ten minutes or read another 10 articles ;)**

Comment: May be its just me but i didn't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, so your [previous problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939333/increment-article-views-on-the-fly-within-one-row-in-codeigniter/13939377#13939377) was solved I believe?

Comment: Yes, green tick approved ;)

Comment: Now I need help with this condition.

Comment: This is a bit thougher now...You need to compare IP, compare timestamps, and keep track of article visited (you don't mention how you're doing it). As for cookies, you can use the cookie_helper, or simply the session class

Comment: I need to figure it out somehow. It is to avoid the separate table for counting hits for every article, which will became enormous after several years. E.g. I have seen a "voting" table on a big poker website and there were millions of records and it slows the website. The voting polls were almost on every page.

Comment: Let me see if I got it right: the user may only clicks 10 articles every 10 minutes? Repeated articles don't count. If the user exceeds the limit, nothing is done.

Did I get it right?

Comment: @Raphael_ he may click as many articles as he wants. Repeated articles (repeated means the same id) don't save in the "10 list" in the cookies.

Comment: Ye, I meant, he may click as many articles as he wants, but if it gets above 10/10min, we just don't count it. Is that right?

Comment: E.g. the id that is clicked as 11th will replace the 1st (but before that check if it is not already one of the previous 10). If it is unique(not already read) allow php update code execution to run and replace 1st id in the list in the cookie)

Comment: Should we update the timestamp if the user clicks the same article again?

Comment: @Derfder, I seriously think that it would be much easier to help if you could just rephrase what you are trying to achieve and your requirements more clearly, e.g. in steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Raphael_ code and your question you can try this:

```
    <?php
            $aClicks = $this->session
                ->userdata('article_clicks');
        $nextId = $this->session->userdata('nextId');
        // Initialize the array, if it's not already initialized
        if ($aClicks == false) {
            $aClicks = array();
            $nextId = 0;
        }
        // Now, we clean our array for the articles that have been clicked longer than
       // 10 minutes ago.
        $aClicks = array_filter($aClicks, function($click) {
                    return (time() - $click['time']) < 600; // Less than 10 minutes elapsed
                }
        );
// We check if the article clicked is already in the list
        $found = false;
        foreach ($aClicks as $click) {
            if ($click['article'] === $id) { // Assuming $id holds the article id
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
// If it's not, we add it
        if (!$found) {
            $aClicks[$nextId] = array(
                'article' => $id, // Assuming $id holds the article id
                'time' => time()
            );
            $nextId++;
            $this->session->set_userdata('nextId', $nextId);
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata('article_clicks', $aClicks);
        if (count($aClicks) > 10 && $nextId > 9) {
            $this->session->set_userdata('nextId', 0);
            echo "OK!";

        }
    ?>
```

Comment: I have tried it and it is not working. If I refresh the page e.g. 20 times the same article the db update function after // do something is executed every time. I guess the if condition need to have also the timestamp check not just count($aClicks) < 10 . What do you think?

Comment: Any idea how to make the condition better?

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely go for Sessions. It saves you bandwidth consumption and is much easier to handle. Unless, of course, you need the data on the client-side, which, by your explanation, I assume you don't. Assuming you went for sessions, all you gotta do is store an array with the data you have. The following code should do it:

```
$aClicks = $this->session
                ->userdata('article_clicks');

// Initialize the array, if it's not already initialized
if ($aClicks == false) {
    $aClicks = array();
}

// Now, we clean our array for the articles that have been clicked longer than
// 10 minutes ago.
$aClicks = array_filter(
    $aClicks,
    function($click) {
        return (time() - $click['time']) < 600; // Less than 10 minutes elapsed
    }
);

// We check if the article clicked is already in the list
$found = false;
foreach ($aClicks as $click) {
    if ($click['article'] === $id) { // Assuming $id holds the article id
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

// If it's not, we add it
if (!$found) {
    $aClicks[] = array(
        'article' => $id, // Assuming $id holds the article id
        'time'    => time()
    );
}

// Store the clicks back to the session
$this->session
     ->set_userdata('article_clicks', $aClicks);


// If we meet all conditions
if (count($aClicks) < 10) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thumb up for your time ;). I will check it in several minutes and let you know if it works.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that with echo "OK"; die(); and it works well, but after 10 clicks on different articles, it ignored it always. I need to remember the clicked stuff for another ten click and then reset that only for the first row. E.g. after 10 click the id and timestamp will not became 11 row but will replace the 1st row in the list.

Comment: I think it needs to be rewritten a little bit to work as expected. Any advice?

Comment: I have updated my original post and set a bounty 100 points, so you could try to improve your code and if it will work I will coose you answer as the winning answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess the easy solution for this would be to add the current index on session and increment it by one everytime.
When you reach 9 make it 0 again.

Comment: Thanks for an idea. Could you put out some code as an naswer so I can try it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't been at home for the last few days. Will check it out in a moment,

Comment: Ok, ok. I think I hadn't got your request correctly. Let me try to rephrase it and see if that's what you meant: __You wanna do something every time the user reads 10 articles. The article should only be counted to that '10 read articles' list if it hasn't been read for the last 10 minutes. Is that right?__

Answer (score 2):

I assumne that $clicks is an array with up to ten visited articles. The id is used as key and the timestamp as value. $id is the id of the new article.

```
$clicks = $this->session->userdata('article_clicks');

//default value
$clicks = ($clicks)? $clicks : array();

//could be loaded from config
$maxItemCount = 10;
$timwToLive= 600;

//helpers
$time = time();
$deadline = $time - $timeToLive;

//add if not in list
if(! isset($clicks[$id]) ){
  $clicks[$id] = $time;
}
//remove old values
$clicks = array_filter($clicks, function($value){ $value >= $deadline;});

//sort newest to oldest
arsort($clicks);

//limit items, oldest will be removed first because we sorted the array
$clicks = array_slice($clicks, 0, $maxItemCount);

//save to session
$this->session->>set_userdata('article_clicks',$clicks)
```

Usage:

```
//print how mch time has passed since the last visit
if(isset($clicks[$id]){
  echo "visited ".($time-$clicks[$id]). "seconds ago." ;
} else {
  echo "first visit";
}
```

**EDIT:** you have to use arsort not rsort or the keys will be lost, sorry

Comment: Hmm, I am getting Content Encoding Error
      
      
      
      
      
        
        
          The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

Comment: OK, I solved that but now  I get always first visit ;( even if i refresh or revisit the page

Comment: Not working, I have corrected $timwToLive= 600; to $timeToLive= 600; but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: print_r($clicks) is always empty ;( no matter how many times I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood correctly what you need.

Usage:

```
$this->load->library('click');
$this->click->add($id, time());
```

The class API is very simple and the code is commented. You can also check if an item `expired()`, if `exists()` and you can `get()` item saved time.

Remember that:

- Each item will expire after 10 minutes (*see `$ttl`*)
- Only 10 items are saved in session (*see `$max_entries`*)

  ```
  class Click
  {
      /**
       * CI instance
       * @var object
       */
      private $CI;

      /**
       * Click data holder
       * @var array
       */
      protected $clicks = array();

      /**
       * Time until an entry will expire
       * @var int
       */
      protected $ttl = 600;

      /**
       * How much entries do we store ?
       * @var int
       */
      protected $max_entries = 10;

      // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

      public function __construct()
      {
          $this->CI =& get_instance();

          if (!class_exists('CI_Session')) {
              $this->CI->load->library('session');
          }

          // load existing data from user's session
          $this->fetch();
      }

      // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

      /**
       * Add a new page
       *
       * @access  public
       * @param   int     $id     Page ID
       * @param   int     $time   Added time (optional)
       * @return  bool
       */
      public function add($id, $time = null)
      {
          // If page ID does not exist and limit has been reached, stop here
          if (!$this->exist($id) AND (count($this->clicks) == $this->max_entries)) {
              return false;
          }

          $time = !is_null($time) ? $time : time();

          if ($this->expired($id)) {
              $this->clicks[$id] = $time;
              return true;
          }

          return false;
      }

      /**
       * Get specified page ID data
       *
       * @access  public
       * @param   int     $id     Page ID
       * @return  int|bool        Added time or `false` on error
       */
      public function get($id)
      {
          return ($this->exist($id)) ? $this->clicks[$id] : false;
      }

      /**
       * Check if specified page ID exists
       *
       * @access  public
       * @param   int     $id Page ID
       * @return  bool
       */
      public function exist($id)
      {
          return isset($this->clicks[$id]);
      }

      /**
       * Check if specified page ID expired
       *
       * @access  public
       * @param   int     $id Page ID
       * @return  bool
       */
      public function expired($id)
      {
          // id does not exist, return `true` so it can added
          if (!$this->exist($id)) {
              return true;
          }

          return ((time() - $this->clicks[$id]) >= $this->ttl) ? true : false;
      }

      /**
       * Store current clicks data in session
       *
       * @access  public
       * @return  object  Click
       */
      public function save()
      {
          $this->CI->session->set_userdata('article_clicks', serialize($this->clicks));

          return $this;
      }

      /**
       * Load data from user's session
       *
       * @access  public
       * @return  object  Click
       */
      public function fetch()
      {
          if ($data = $this->CI->session->userdata('article_clicks')) {
              $this->clicks = unserialize($data);
          }

          return $this;
      }

      public function __destruct()
      {
          $this->save();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Hmm, I m gettign this error Warning: include(application/errors/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: That error is not related with this library. Check your application configuration, directories names and if you changed `index.php` undo them.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily wrap that into a class of it's own that serializes the information into a string and that is able to manipulate the data, e.g. to add another value while taking care to cap at the maximum of ten elements.

A potential usage could look like, let's assume the cookie *last* would contain 256 at start:

```
echo $_COOKIE['last'] = (new StringQueue($_COOKIE['last']))->add(10), "\n";
echo $_COOKIE['last'] = (new StringQueue($_COOKIE['last']))->add(20), "\n";
echo $_COOKIE['last'] = (new StringQueue($_COOKIE['last']))->add(30), "\n";
echo $_COOKIE['last'] = (new StringQueue($_COOKIE['last']))->add(40), "\n";
echo $_COOKIE['last'] = (new StringQueue($_COOKIE['last']))->add(50), "\n";
echo $_COOKIE['last'] = (new StringQueue($_COOKIE['last']))->add(60), "\n";
echo $_COOKIE['last'] = (new StringQueue($_COOKIE['last']))->add(70), "\n";
echo $_COOKIE['last'] = (new StringQueue($_COOKIE['last']))->add(80), "\n";
echo $_COOKIE['last'] = (new StringQueue($_COOKIE['last']))->add(90), "\n";
echo $_COOKIE['last'] = (new StringQueue($_COOKIE['last']))->add(100), "\n";
```

And the output ([Demo](http://eval.in/5419)):

```
10,256
20,10,256
30,20,10,256
40,30,20,10,256
50,40,30,20,10,256
60,50,40,30,20,10,256
70,60,50,40,30,20,10,256
80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,256
90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,256
100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10
```

A rough implementation of that:

```
class StringQueue implements Countable
{
    private $size = 10;
    private $separator = ',';
    private $values;

    public function __construct($string) {
        $this->values = $this->parseString($string);
    }

    private function parseString($string) {
        $values = explode($this->separator, $string, $this->size + 1);
        if (isset($values[$this->size])) {
            unset($values[$this->size]);
        }
        return $values;
    }

    public function add($value) {
        $this->values = $this->parseString($value . $this->separator . $this);
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return implode(',', $this->values);
    }

    public function count() {
        return count($this->values);
    }
}
```

It's just some basic string operations, here with [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) and [`explode`](http://php.net/explode).

Comment: Soory, but I don't understand what you suggest at all. Can you clarify it more, thanks. Is your code possible in CI?

Comment: The code works in PHP, it also works in CI. Just add the article when it's clicked (you might want to remove duplicates, that has not been coded therein).